# S3 uploading and serving image with pre signed URL

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image to my S3 bucket through a pre-signed url. Everything works well except that when I hit the public URL for that image, the browser downloads it instead of showing it. When I upload the same image from the AWS Console, everything works well and the image gets displayed in the browser.

**Here how I do it:**

Generation of the pre-signed URL:

```
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
    Bucket: myBucket,
    Key: myKey,
    Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
})
```

Upload of the file with axios:

```
const response = await axios.put(url, formElement.files[0])
```

*Should I configure headers somewhere in the process to tell S3 the mime type of the content I'm uploading or something like this?*

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two places you can do this.

If you know the type of image ahead of time, then you can explicitly set the `ContentType` in the `s3.getSignedUrl` params. This is because those params will be encoded and passed with the signed put request: [getSignedUrl docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) / [putObject docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property). So for example:

```
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
    Bucket: myBucket,
    Key: myKey,
    Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds,
    ContentType: 'image/png'
});
```

Alternatively, you can set the `Content-Type` header on the Axios request [REST PUT docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html), for example:

```
const response = await axios.put(
  url,
  formElement.files[0],
  { headers: { 'Content-Type': formElement.files[0].type } });
```

Comment: Thank you, doing it in the axios request works well, and I can dynamically set the content type: `const response = await axios.put(url, formElement.files[0], {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': formElement.files[0].type
          }
        })`

Comment: Good point- I'll update the answer to include the dynamic mime typing as that's more useful :)